# Functions in C not returning proper pointer types?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm working on a block-cipher program in C, and it seems none of my functions are returning the proper type of pointer, so my code won't even compile.

An example is this:

```
char *evenString(char * inText)   /*takes a string of text.  If it has an odd number of     chars, it adds ASCII char 19 as padding.*/
{
  int inputLength = strlen(inText);
  char* evenText; /*pointer to character array*/  
  if(inputLength%2) /*If even, pad*/
    {
      evenText = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (inputLength+2)); 
      strcpy(evenText,inText);
      evenText[inputLength] = FILLER_CHARACTER;
    }
  else
    {    
      evenText = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (inputLength+1));
      strcpy(evenText,inText);
    }

  return evenText; /*which should be a char*, right?*/

}
```

When I call it in main, the call looks like this:

```
char *plainText =  evenString(inputText);
```

And the compiler brings up these exceptions:

```
block_cypher.c:28:22: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
char *plainText =  evenString(inputText);

block_cypher.c: At top level:
block_cypher.c:38:7: error: conflicting types for ‘evenString’
char *evenString(char * inText)

block_cypher.c:28:22: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘evenString’ was here
char *plainText =  evenString(inputText);

block_cypher.c: In function ‘evenString’:
block_cypher.c:45:26: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function    ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
   evenText = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (inputLength+2)); 

block_cypher.c:53:26: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function  ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
   evenText = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (inputLength+1));
```

It's like this for all my functions, which all return a pointer of type int* or char*.  I haven't even been able to compile, so I don't even know where to begin to fix this.  Any insight to this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time!

UPDATE: Thank you all! I followed all your advice:

1. I inserted function prototypes, which resolved many of the errors right away.
2. I included ; I don't know what I was thinking, but I've been working in a Java IDE a lot recently and forgot a lot of important stuff about C.
3. As suggested, I stopped casting malloc().  My C professor told us that since malloc returns a VOID* pointer, it's always good practice to cast it.

Thank you all!

Comment: You have a bug in the "even" case, you fail to null-terminate the string you're returning.

Comment: Also you must `#include <stdlib.h>` (that is the source of the last 2 errors you posted). In C99 you must declare functions before calling them; that goes for `malloc` as well as for `evenString`.

Comment: Note: if you are the sort of person who easily uses a function without having provided a prototype, you should **not** cast the result of `malloc()`. Doing so will only prevent the compiler from telling you that you are doing something very wrong, causing a crash at run-time instead. http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Comment: Thank you Matt, I didn't catch either of those things.  That's what I get for working in Java I guess!  Fixed the terminate in the odd case (which I mislabled).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below error:

```
block_cypher.c:28:22: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘evenString’ was here
//                                   ^^^^^^^^
char *plainText =  evenString(inputText);
```

indicates that at the location where the `evenString` function is invoked, the compiler doesn't know that function's signature, which usually means you are missing proper header file. As a result of that, the compiler deduces its own declaration (based on supplied arguments), with return type **defaulted to** `int`:

```
int evenString(char* inText);
```

And this is where the error originates from:

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
//                                    ^^^^ ^^^^^^^
```

After reading all errors / warnings it looks that you **define** the `evenString` function **after** its first usage. You should either *declare* the function before its first usage, or move entire *function definition* to the top of your translation unit (at least before you use that function for the first time).

That is:

```
block_cypher.c: At top level:
block_cypher.c:38:7: error: conflicting types for ‘evenString’
//             ^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^
char *evenString(char * inText)

block_cypher.c:28:22: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘evenString’ was here
//             ^^  
char *plainText =  evenString(inputText);
```

means you have invoked `evenString(inputText);` at line **28**, where the compiler deduced the return type to be `int`, and only then you declare/define the function at line **38**, which is too late (at least without previous declaration).

To make it working, try adding declaration before that **28** th line:

```
char* evenString(char* inText);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a prototype for `evenString()` before calling the function.

Without a prototype the compiler assumes it returns a value of type `int` and the assignment

```
char *plainText =  evenString(inputText);
```

is like

```
char *plainText =  <int value here>;
```

so the compiler complains